# If I have a quadratic form, is there a fast way to find its matrix?

Tags: quadratics, bilinear-form

Suppose I have a quadratic form such that:

$$ q(x,y,z)= 5x^2 + 5y^2 + 2z^2 - 2xy + 4xz + 4yz$$

Its matrix in the standard basis is:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
5 &  -1& 2\\ 
-1 &  5& 2\\ 
 2&2  &2 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Is there a fast way to find it? Doing it the slow way is the only way I know. I.e the slow way is to pick all the elements $e_i$ and $e_j$ from the standard basis and see what the bilinear form $\phi$ such that $\phi(x,x) = q(x)$ gives for all $\phi (e_i, e_j)$.

So any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the quadratic form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy$ the corresponding matrix is $$\left(\begin{matrix}a&h&g\\h&b&f\\g&f&c\end{matrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A=[a_{ij}]$ is the matrix of $q$, then we have
$$ q(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}x_ix_j $$

This means that $a_{ii}$ is equal to the coefficient of $x_i^2$ in $q$, while if $i\neq j$ then $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ij}$ are each equal to half the coefficient of $x_ix_j$ in $q$.

Note that this works with your example if we replace $x,y,z$ with $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, if the mixed coefficients $yz,zx,xy$ are all even, then the form
$$ A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + R yz + S zx + T xy $$ gives Gram matrix (half Hessian)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
A & \frac{T}{2} & \frac{S}{2} \\
\frac{T}{2} & B & \frac{R}{2} \\
\frac{S}{2} & \frac{R}{2} & C
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If $R,S,T$ are not even, usually this is doubled, just use the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives

For the doubled version see page 401 in [Lehman](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Lehman_1992.pdf) or page 104 of [Watson](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Watson_Representation_1954.pdf)

$$\begin{array}{l}\text{If I had a quadratic form,}\cr
\text{I'd form in the morning}\cr
\text{I'd form in the evening}\cr
\text{All over this land}\cr
\text{I'd form out danger}\cr
\text{I'd form out a warning}\cr
\text{I'd form out the love between}\cr
\text{My brothers and my sisters}\cr
\text{All over this land.}\end{array}$$

[Pete Seeger (1956)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rl-yszPdRTk)

[Peter, Paul, and Mary (1963)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxWTDcP9Y5E)